# Libgdx ShapeRenderer rectangles

Tags: libgdx

I'm trying to draw a filled rectangle in Libgdx and according to the API this should work:

`shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.FilledRectangle);`

But it gives me an error and tells me to change `FilledRectangle` to `Filled`, `Point`or `Line`.

imports: `import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer;`

Any ideas on what is causing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you read [the documentation](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.html), you'll see that `ShapeRenderer.ShapeType` is an enum with the following values defined:

```
Filled 
Line 
Point
```

So the error message you're receiving is accurate.

If you want to draw a filled rectangle, choose the `Filled` enum type, then use shape rederer to draw a rectangle:

```
 shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
 shapeRenderer.identity();
 shapeRenderer.translate(20, 12, 2);
 shapeRenderer.rotate(0, 0, 1, 90);
 shapeRenderer.rect(-width / 2, -height / 2, width, height);
 shapeRenderer.end();
```

Answer (score 2):

With LibGdx 0.9.8 they removed `ShapeyType.Rectangle`, `ShapeType.FilledRectangle` and introduced `Filled, Line, Point` to optimize the shape rendering.